# Best way to retrieve hierarchical data from database

Tags: database, hierarchical-trees

I have to store blog style comments in a database. Each comment can have a parent one.

I am doing it with a column called "parentComment" that has a null value when it is a top level comment or have a value if it is a response to another comment.

What is the most efficient way to retrieve a comment and all its childs?

Comment: On which DBMS?  They differ in how they do hierarchical queries.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficientelegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree

Comment: I agree with Dawkins, but, anyway, here is another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801/sql-how-to-store-and-navigate-hierarchies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite common technique is to also have a (duplicate, indirectly) relation to the "root" of the tree, which means you can select the full tree in one neat select. Othewise it quickly gets dirty.