# What the best way to handle categories, sub-categories - hierachical data?

Tags: sql, tree, rdbms, hierarchical-data

#### Duplicate:

> [SQL - how to store and navigate hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801/sql-how-to-store-and-navigate-hierarchies)

---

If I have a database where the client requires categories, sub-categories, sub-sub-categories and so on, what's the best way to do that?  If they only needed three, and always knew they'd need three I could just create three tables cat, subcat, subsubcat, or the like.  But what if they want further depth?  I don't like the three tables but it's the only way I know how to do it.

I have seen the "[sql adjacency list](http://www.sqlsummit.com/AdjacencyList.htm)" but didn't know if that was the only way possible.  I was hoping for input so that the client can have any level of categories and subcategories. I believe this means hierarchical data.

EDIT: Was hoping for the sql to get the list back out if possible

Thank you.

Comment: You've been around here long enough to know this'll be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table categories: id, title, parent_category_id


 id | title | parent_category_id
----+-------+-------------------
  1 |  food |              NULL
  2 | pizza |                 1
  3 | wines |              NULL
  4 |   red |                 3
  5 | white |                 3
  6 | bread |                 1
```

I usually do a `select *` and assemble the tree algorithmically in the application layer.

Comment: But what if you to relate one category with two parent catecorys? ;-)

Comment: @Patrik: nodes in tree structures have only got 1 parent. This is what I assumed here. If you need the possibility for more than one parent, then you'd need another table to relate a node with multiple parents.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at Joe Celko's book, or [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801/sql-how-to-store-and-navigate-hierarchies).

Answer (score 0):

creating a table with a relation to itself is the best way for doing the same. its easy and flexible to the extent you want it to be without any limitation. I dont think i need to repeat the structure that you should put since that has already been suggested in the 1st answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a number of methods, but still stick to the plain `"id, parent_id"` intra-table relationship, where root items have `parent_id=0`. If you need to query the items in a tree a lot, especially when you only need 'branches', or all underlying elements of one node, you could use a second table: `"id, path_id, level"` holding a reference to *each* node in the upward path of *each* node. This might look like a lot of data, but it drastically improves the branch-lookups when used, and is quite manageable to render in triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Not a recommended method, but I have seen people use dot-notation on the data.
Food.Pizza or Wines.Red.Cabernet

You end up doing lots of Like or midstring queries which don't use indices terribly well. And you end up parsing things alot.