# Hierarchical storage data in MySQL database, category tree and SELECT query

Tags: mysql, database, storage, categories, hierarchical

I created two tables and uploaded it to trusted imgur.com to show you an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/viIsR.jpg

// EDIT looks like imgur is down, uploaded to another site:
http://images.tinypic.pl/i/00761/0ies71okcyxd.png

As it is in the example above, you see, that

- PANTIES
- CORSET
- SOCKS
- PAJAMA

belongs to parent 5, which belongs to category 5, it means to UNDERWEAR and that category  belongs to parent 1, which means that it belong to category 1 called CLOTHES.

I'm reading examples on sites like these below:

[www.phpro.org/tutorials/Managing-Hierarchical-Data-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Managing-Hierarchical-Data-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html)

[mysql hierarchy storage with large trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114280/mysql-hierarchy-storage-with-large-trees)

http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/

https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns

[What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)

and I still can not figure out how to display path of:

- ALL CLOTHES,
- ALL UNDERWEAR (PANTIES, CORSET, SOCKS, PAJAMA).

I can only display for example:

- PAJAMA

  ```
      SELECT 
          t.path
      FROM 
          thumbnails t
      LEFT JOIN 
          categories c
      ON
          t.category = c.category
      WHERE
          t.category = 9
  ```

where 9 = PAJAMA

Answer (score 1):

This is my all-time favorite way to manage hierarchical data in mysql:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

```
table example:
id     name     lft    rgt
1      clothes  1      10
2      tops     2      3
3      bottoms  4      9
4      pants    5      6
5      shorts   7      8
```

this allows you to have a hierarchy like this:

clothes
+--Tops
+--bottoms
+----pants
+----shorts

Comment: I know this article and I like it, but this is not a full answer. I still do not know how to display for example all UNDERWEAR'S path*s.

Comment: The issue is that you cannot do a path query of unlimited depth on a data structure like this.  You need to change the data structure to accommodate paths of any depth.  Then, you need to do a self-join:  SELECT * FROM table_a as parent join table_a as child.