# The best way to store tree-like data in database

Tags: database

Since database stores data as 2d table, I want to store treelike data into database, with little space waste.How can I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801/sql-how-to-store-and-navigate-hierarchies

Comment: This decision also depends on your DBMS. With a modern DBMS recursive queries are easy and quite efficient (in that case the id/parentid approach works fine).  But if your DBMS doesn't support that, you will need to find a differetn solution

Answer (score 0):

Saving data with tree like structure with space: you will run out of space for trees having larger hierachy.

try this

```
PkId Name  ParentId(FkId to PkId )
---------------------
1    root    0
2    child1  1
3    child2  1
4    child3  2
```

then you can us a function to  generate the tree structure.