# Updating Inserted record using triggerc

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table where I need to update a column's value with the Identity of the Inserted record.

Following is the trigger I have written:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateRecordID]
on [dbo].[Employee]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    UPDATE dbo.Employee
    SET RecordID = (SELECT EmployeeID FROM INSERTED ) WHERE EmployeeID= (SELECT EmployeeID FROM INSERTED )
END
```

The trigger is created successfully but when I Insert a record into the table I get the following error:

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level
>   exceeded (limit 32).

If I don't put the where condition in the update statement and write the trigger as following:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateRecordID]
on [dbo].[Employee]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    UPDATE dbo.Employee
    SET RecordID = (SELECT EmployeeID FROM INSERTED )
END
```

I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

What is the best practice to Update a record to keep the Primary Key in another column so that I can add more records in the same table and keep them related?

I can write the Update statement in the Stored Procedure where I am inserting the record using @@Identity but I wanted to do the same using a trigger.

Comment: I'm a little confused, why do you need the same ID twice in the same table?

Comment: I need that so that I can insert another record in the same table and make the relation between the two records based on that same ID.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a relationship table? You can then have more than one link between records and you can enforce constraints.

Comment: But when you insert another record, trigger will fill that record's `RecordID` with that record's `EmployeeID`. How do you plan to have relation between them?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic you are right but the situation is something that is asking me to keep the identity in 2 columns. Though I can make some more adjustments so I don't need to do this, I just wanted to know if this can be done or not...

Comment: Have a look at this SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04fd5/2

Comment: OK several poor rpractices here. Don;t use a subquery for inteh update use a join and under no circumstances shoudl you ever use @@identity in a database that has triggers or you will have data intergrity problems!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You should join your table on INSERTED table as it can contain more rows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateRecordID]
on [dbo].[Employee]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    UPDATE e
    SET RecordID = i.EmployeeID 
    FROM dbo.Employee e
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i on i.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
END
```

Comment: This will work but I propse that the OP is wanting to do something that is not really necessary - afterall, why keep the same ID in two seperate columns? Surely this is just adding overhead to the server and also keeping redundant data. I suggest that the design of the database may need to be examined rather than rely on a trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this give the 1st error I have mentioned in the question.

I want to keep the ID in two columns because I need to insert records which can be related to records inside the same table.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I agree completely. I supposed OP have some other way and logic to later update `RecordID` for specific rows, and this is just to set some initial value.  This is just fix of above trigger.

Comment: @Chatur - this query itself could not possibly produce the above mentioned error. It is probably some other `ON UPDATE` trigger that's causing it. Check for them, please.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic That's a good point...will get back on this...
I think I have got the answer...

Comment: @NenadZivkovic It was the issue you mention in your last comment.

Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best practice to Update a record to keep the Primary Key in another column so that I can add more records in the same table and keep them related?

I think you're looking to represent a hierarchy.  Normally the column that holds the relation will be null for rows that have no parent, rather than having their own PK copied into that.

An example:

```
create table Items (
      ID int not null primary key identity(1, 1)
    , Name varchar(50) not null unique
    , ParentID int null references Items (ID)
);
insert into Items (Name, ParentID) select 'Parent', null;
insert into Items (Name, ParentID) select 'Child', ID from Items where Name = 'Parent';
```

Notice that we don't need triggers and inserting children records is quite easy.

There are also [other methods to representing a hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801/sql-how-to-store-and-navigate-hierarchies) in SQL including SQL Server's own [HierarchyID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx).

As for your error messages, those might indicate that you have some trigger recursion happening.  Check your values for nested and recursive triggers.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I want to avoid to right OR in the select statement where I need to get all the records including the parent record: 

SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee WHERE RecordID=160 OR EmployeeID=160

Comment: @Chatur I suggest that you do not compromise your schema for the sake of less typing.

Comment: Right, I got it, the only solution is to keep the RecordID in the parent record null...

Thanks

Comment: @Chatur I'm not saying it's the only way to make things work, but I simply don't see the need to use triggers to keep a hierarchy like this. Triggers should be somewhat of a last resort these days, as most relational needs have a more elegant solution in a modern RDBMS.