# How to store hierarchical structure data in java?

Tags: java, sql, loops, recursion, iterator

In database table, i have maintained parent and child folder relationship as shown below **datatable**. Using that relationship i need to create hierarchical structure in a jsp web page. To display that structure i used http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk t:tree2 component.My requirement is, I need to fetch data from database and store that relationship in java variable. To do that i need a recursive technique to store tree structure or(hierarchical structure) in java variable. Please help to find answer.

**DataTable:**
[image]

**hierarchical View of Directory structure:**
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Tricky. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801/sql-how-to-store-and-navigate-hierarchies

Comment: Showing the present implemented code has no use because it's not traversing to depth of the constructing tree. It's constructing one level tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion to iterate over it.

```
void processChilds(Item child) {
List<Item> childs = selectChilds(child);
    for(Item i: childs) {
       //do smth
       processChilds(i);
    }
}
```

Or you need to select all records at once and then parse it into your own structure of objects. It can be HashMap or your own tree-like structure.

```
class Item {
  List<Item> childs;
}
```

I suggest you go with the first one (because it's simple to code) unless your tree is really deep

Comment: what selectChilds(child) method does in that context?!!

Comment: database call like "select colum2 from table where column1 = ?"
and ? is the name of current folder. 
but you'll need to add ROOT folder to your db

Comment: k, processChilds(Item child) also have list type parameter. I'm using java 1.4 which does not supports generics and for loop(use used). I guess i need to pass single folderName to processChilds()method so that i can get childs of it from selectChilds(child) method. Sorry if i'm bothering you. Thanks

Comment: I suggest to use java 7 since even java 6 has reached it's end of life.
You need to write 'selectChilds' by your own. So parameters are up to you.

You can write 'List childs' instead of 'List<Item> childs'

Comment: I used recursive method(one you suggested) to accomplish requisite task. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Node class having list of child nodes and other required state variables like isdirectory etc. Request you to search again on SO with "Tree Like Data Structure in Java". I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a tree structure in Java is almost identical as in any other language. You should read up on [Data Structures and Algorithms](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Java-International/dp/0470398809/).

Depending on how you are going to use it you data structure will vary. A perfectly good way that is easy to traverse upward is this:

```
class Node
{
   private Node parent;
   private int value;
}
```

Together with a hash lookup on leafs (or nodes if you want the whole tree searchable) you have a perfect way to find the path to any file and it's path using such a structure. This structure cannot be used if you have a node and want to find it's children. Then a more conventional tree already shown as one of the answers can be used.