# Self-referential class: How to get jerarchical structure of employees in a company?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.1

I have a class defined in Python called `Employees`. Its attribute `id_supervisor` is the `id` of the employee who is in charge of him.

One employee can be in charge of (supervise) many other employees.

This is my class:

```
class Employee(DeclarativeBase):

    __tablename__ = 'employees'

    id_ = Column('id',Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(50))
    id_supervisor = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employees.id'))
    #other attributes ...
```

What I need to do is to get the whole hierarchical structure of the company, from the boss of the company (he would have his `id_supervisor` attribute set to `None` or to himself) to the lowest worker of the company (he would be supervising no workers at all).

How could this be done? I have been thinking about using a recursive function, but I really don't know how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're concept/table design seems sufficient. What does your source for this information look like? That, I think, will determine your next steps.

Comment: That's the main problem with the adjacency list pattern - you cannot get a whole tree (or a whole branch of the tree) in a single query. You may want to consider using the nested sets (aka modified preorder tree traversal) pattern instead : http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: How would you do this using just SQL, ignoring the SQLAlchemy part? If you don't know the answer to that, [then you should look into that first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801/sql-how-to-store-and-navigate-hierarchies). If you do know the answer, then you should be able to do it with SQLAlchemy (since anything you can do in SQL you can use SQLAlchemy to do), so what part precisely of SQLAlchemy are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the material https://class.coursera.org/db/wiki/coursematerials. You can see the section on recursion (Recursion in SQL). It is explained very well with PostgreSQL examples.

```
postgres=# select * from employees ;
 empid | supervisorid 
-------+--------------
     1 |             
     2 |             
     3 |            1
     4 |            2
     5 |            3
     6 |            4
(6 rows)

WITH RECURSIVE emp(empid,supervisorid) AS (
     SELECT empid, supervisorid  FROM employees where empid=1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT e.empid, e.supervisorid
     FROM emp s, employees e
     WHERE e.supervisorid = s.empid 
   )
SELECT * 
 FROM emp
 ;
 empid | supervisorid 
-------+--------------
     1 |             
     3 |            1
     5 |            3
(3 rows)
```